# Updating Column with new Entry

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers, oracle11g

I created a table with the following attributes:

```
VendorAccount(
  Ven_AccountId, 
  Ven_RegNo,   
  Ven_TxDate,   
  Ven_Invoice_RefNo,    
  TotalAmount,
  Paid_ToVen ,    
  Balance
)
```

In the above table when I select `Ven_Invoice_RefNo` from POP up LOV it gives me the `TotalAmount` from another Table.I want that whenever I enter the value in  `Paid_ToVen` column ,that amount should be subtracted from `Total_Amount` as `Balance` and the new subtracted value should be shown in `TotalBalance` column in next Entry. Below is the report for the table.
[image: Report]

I want the updated value i-e 2300 in `TotalAmount` Column in new entry. Is there any Trigger or Query .

Comment: Can you show your current `select, insert` statements?

Comment: You need to do a trigger on update. I know it in sql. Oracle is a bit different. Search in google

Comment: @bonCodiho  select VEN_INV_REF,sum(unitprice * ven_itemquantity) as total from vendor_invoicedetails group by ven_inv_ref; it is the query through which i get Total Balance.

Comment: @polin . No Problem ,Let me know in SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a `trigger` after update. You will need a logic like the following. Please user the correct fields as per your table and try it out.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_totalBalance AFTER UPDATE ON vendoraccount
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE new_balance INT;
  DECLARE new_total INT;
  DECLARE new_paid INT;

   SELECT balance INTO old_balance, 
   total INTO old_total,
   paidtoven INTO new_paid 
   FROM vendoraccount
   WHERE ven_regno = new.ven_regno
   AND ven_invoice_refno = new.ven_invoice_refno;

   -- depending on your current balance update logic,
   --  you could wrap this update with an IF/ELSE
   -- IF XYZ THEN
   UPDATE vendoraccount SET totalamount = old_total + old_balance - new_paid,
   balance = totalamount - new_paid
   WHERE ven_regno = new.ven_regno
   AND ven_invoice_refno = new.ven_invoice_refno;
   -- END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Just want to ask you, how do you *update* your balance currently? Do you update your balance = total-paid? Or do you leave it as 0? Can you show us your current queries for this table?

Comment: i leave it as 0.Balance column is not necessary as far as i am concerned in this table

Comment: @MuhammadUsman If this answer helps you please mark it up to wrap the question. So anyone else's effort can be saved for other questions and requests like yours :)